# importing ConnectButton from web3uikit gives Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, solidity

I am using nextjs along with tailwind css and a bunch of other libraries like web3uikit.
the app work totally fine but as soon as I import ConnectButton from web3uikit and use it in the sidebar component, it gives me the following error:
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Here's the link to the github repo, just cloning and install the dependencies would help you in setting up the project and then npm run dev.

Link: https://github.com/oneknucklehead/marketplace-web3

Comment: Could you provide example with explained case?

Comment: I am using web3uikit for connecting wallet. The app works completely fine when I haven't import any components from the web3uikit library but as soon as I import the component named "ConnectButton" from the library and use it, it gives me the above said error.
Visit the repo here once:
https://github.com/oneknucklehead/marketplace-web3/blob/main/components/Sidebar.js

try using the connect button component and then not using the connect button component.

Comment: I think is related to nextjs and ssr, did you post your question here: https://forum.moralis.io/t/web3uikit-with-nextjs-airbnb-clone/13727/19

Comment: i didn't, but it seems it addresses the same problem. I have tried all the solution given in the forum, none of them worked for me.

Comment: What `web3uikit` version are you using? Have you tried upgrading to the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Go to node_modules -> web3uikit-> node_modules and delete the react folder under it.

web3uikit node module has a version of react pre-installed with it. Apparently, that's causing errors. Now, why does deleting the folder fix the error? Honestly, I don't know, but it removed the error. This answer is from someone named David MacDonald.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a server-side rendering issue! A screenshot of how I got the `<ConnectButton />` to render in a nextjs application is below:

[Implementing the ConnectButton Component Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEy2C.png)

When the error popped up saying I had an invalid hook call, I closed the error box and the button was rendered in and when I click on it, it showed the web3Modal with the proper sign-in options. I thought that maybe it was a server-side issue

So I fixed it by using a useState hook with a boolean value as seen in the screenshot. It is false by default but will only become true when the component loads in(used a useEffect hook to implement) and I take advantage of that via conditional rendering which is also shown in the screenshot. Once I did that, I haven't encountered the issue at all! Hope this helps!

Comment: Also side note! I forgot to include the empty dependency array for the useEffect hook:

`useEffect(() => {
        setLoadButton(true)
    }, [])`

Comment: Please do not use images for code, use code snippets instead.